# Does run .htaccess file of php website on windows server ? is that right way?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

I developed a PHP website using wamp server, am hosting it on windows server.
I have a file name `.htaccess` which contains rewrite rule for URL. it works on my localhost but does not work on the windows server.
what will I do?
can I create a web.config file?

please help me, Sir/Madam, Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

can you show the .htaccess code?
 or try this code on top of your .htaccess file.
use  https in place of HTTP if have SSL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

use this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^category category.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^cat_id/([^/]*)$ /doha_classified/ad_list.php?cat_id=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^ad_id/([^/]*)$ /doha_classified/search_an_ad.php?ad_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks         
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^category category.php [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^cat_id/([^/]*)$ /doha_classified/ad_list.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^ad_id/([^/]*)$ /doha_classified/search_an_ad.php?ad_id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

ok lets try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^index index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^home index [L,QSA]
```

for home page only if work adds for another one.